# jQuery com efeito blur não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um script jQuery para aplicar efeito blur em uma div enquanto a página sofre um scroll.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
var pixs = $(document).scrollTop()
pixs = pixs / 10;
$('.tudo').css({"-webkit-filter": "blur("+pixs+"px)","filter": "blur("+pixs+"px)"});});
```

A div de class .tudo é o corpo todo da página para testar o efeito, mas nada está funcionando.

Alguém consegue identificar o problema?

**Import do script**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/javascript.js"></script>
```

Comment: Pelo teste aqui tá funcionando. Deve ser outra coisa com erro. Já olhou no console algum erro?

Comment: Você deseja o efeito de blur somente durante o scroll e ao parar volte ao normal?

Comment: Poderia postar o html?

Comment: Eu consegui, o problema estava no overflow do elemento principa, a div .tudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você não está vendo a animação provavelmente está usando um browser diferente dos filtros que está especificando para o css, não esqueça de adicionar os demais para garantir a apresentação esperada em outros browsers.

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var pixs = $(document).scrollTop()
  pixs = pixs / 10;

  $('.tudo').css({
    "-webkit-filter": "blur(" + pixs + "px)",
    "filter": "blur(" + pixs + "px)",
    "-moz-filter": "blur(" + pixs + "px)",
    "-o-filter": "blur(" + pixs + "px)",
    "-ms-filter": "blur(" + pixs + "px)",
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/javascript.js"></script>
<div class="tudo">
  <img src="http://geradormemes.com/media/created/clkhev.jpg" />
</div>
```

Abaixo segue um outro exemplo utilizando uma animação para o blur durante o scroll e a remoção dele depois. O que melhor trabalhado pode dar um efeito de motion blur, que talvez seja o que você esteja procurando.

```js
var scrollTimer = false;

$(document).scroll(function() {

  $('.tudo').removeClass('blur-out');
  $('.tudo').addClass('blur-in');

  if (scrollTimer) {
    clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
  }
  scrollTimer = setTimeout(afterScroll, 200);
});

function afterScroll() {

  $('.tudo').removeClass('blur-in');
  $('.tudo').addClass('blur-out');
}
```

```css
.blur-in {
  -webkit-filter: blur(30px);
  -moz-filter: blur(30px);
  -o-filter: blur(30px);
  -ms-filter: blur(30px);
  filter: blur(30px);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='3');
  -webkit-transition: 1s -webkit-filter linear;
  -moz-transition: 1s -moz-filter linear;
  -o-transition: 1s -o-filter linear;
  transition: 1s filter linear;
}

.blur-out {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  -moz-filter: blur(0px);
  -o-filter: blur(0px);
  -ms-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='3');
  -webkit-transition: .5s -webkit-filter linear;
  -moz-transition: .5s -moz-filter linear;
  -o-transition: .5s -o-filter linear;
  transition: .5s filter linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="tudo">
  <img src="http://geradormemes.com/media/created/clkhev.jpg" />
</div>
```